# Why can't I get Integer input on java?

Tags: java, int

This is my equation generator and the output of the code is always 'incorrect'. I think it's because I can't get the integer input from the user. All I want is to fix this code. If anyone has any idea, please tell me.

THE CODE:

```
package equasionGen;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class EquationGen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("This will Generate you an Equasion with numbers ranging between 1-1000");
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int idx = 1; idx <= 1; ++idx);
        int randomInt = random.nextInt(10);
        Random random1 = new Random();
        for(int idx = 1; idx <= 1; ++idx);
        int randomInt1 = random.nextInt(10);
        System.out.print(randomInt + " + " + randomInt1 + " = ");
        Scanner josh = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = josh.nextInt();
        if (josh.equals(randomInt + randomInt1)){
            System.out.println("CORRECT!!!");
        } else if (!josh.equals (randomInt + randomInt1)){
            System.out.println("INCORRECT!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look closely. What are the two things you're checking if they're equal?

Comment: If one of the answers below works, or doesn't work, let us know.

Comment: Oh man, where to begin? Your for loops are not doing anything. You don't need two separate random number generators. You try to compare your scanner instead of your input. You don't need the `if` after the `else`. I suggest you sit down, think carefully on the steps that solve your assignment, and rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: What do you think your `for` loops do, and why?

Comment: yea ur right, i thought i was getting somewhere with the for loops but then asked this question. i was gonna get rid of them but i forgot. still a beginner that means :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .equals() method is used to compare Strings. For comparing Integers, you should use the "==" comparison operator instead. Also, you are trying to compare the Scanner object "josh" to an Integer of (randomInt + randomInt1). Instead compare the Integer input, which you named "input" to (randomInt + randomInt1).

It should be:

```
if (input == (randomInt + randomInt1)) { ... }
else { ... }
```

If you want to compare two Integers to see if they are not the same, you can use the "!=" operator instead of the "=="

Comment: @JoshuaCiantar If this is correct then please mark the check next to the problem to show that it is correct. Thank you.

Comment: sorry wheres the check? is it a box?

Comment: i cant find the checkbox :/.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see this until now. It seems to be checked already, so hopefully you found it.

Comment: yea i did find it sorry :)